# Using Asc offset and desc in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, offset

This code produces this

```
SELECT "End_Date"+5                                                   
                FROM exhibits e, rooms r, PlaceOfExhibition p
                WHERE "End_Date">CURRENT_DATE+5 AND r."Minimum" >= 7 and
r."Maximum" <= 16 and p."Location"=r."Name" and e."Name" = p."Exhibition" ORDER
BY "End_Date" desc;
  ?column?  
------------
 2017-01-15
 2016-12-20
 2016-10-22
 2016-09-20
(2 rows)
```

I require that `2016-12-20` date(the second biggest one), I don't always need the second biggest one though it depends on what is count is from rooms(if the rooms query returns 4 then I need the fourth biggest one)
I require to get this from a subquery
This is the subquery I have

```
SELECT "End_Date"+5                                                   
                FROM exhibits e, rooms r, PlaceOfExhibition p
                WHERE "End_Date">CURRENT_DATE+5 AND r."Minimum" >= 7 and
r."Maximum" <= 16 and p."Location"=r."Name" and e."Name" = p."Exhibition" ORDER
BY "End_Date" ASC OFFSET (Select Count("Name")-1 FROM Rooms Where "Minimum">=7
and "Maximum"<=16) LIMIT 1 ;
```

Which returns this

```
2016-10-22
```

So my query is getting the second last date but in the wrong direction, it is getting the second smallest instead of the second largest

Comment: Doesn't replacing the "ASC" before the "OFFSET" with "DESC" work?

Comment: You are the smartest person on the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT "End_Date"+5                                                   
                FROM exhibits e, rooms r, PlaceOfExhibition p
                WHERE "End_Date">CURRENT_DATE+5 AND r."Minimum" >= 7 and
r."Maximum" <= 16 and p."Location"=r."Name" and e."Name" = p."Exhibition" ORDER
BY "End_Date" DESC OFFSET (Select Count("Name")-1 FROM Rooms Where "Minimum">=7
and "Maximum"<=16) LIMIT 1 ;
```

Comment: I kind of just want a way to put ORDER BY "End_Date" desc in stead of ORDER BY "End_Date" but the ASC get's in the way, do you know how to do that?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to re-order the results:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT "End_Date"+5                                                   
    FROM exhibits e, rooms r, PlaceOfExhibition p
    WHERE "End_Date">CURRENT_DATE+5
    AND r."Minimum" >= 7
    AND r."Maximum" <= 16
    AND p."Location"=r."Name"
    AND e."Name" = p."Exhibition"
    ORDER BY "End_Date" desc
) x
ORDER BY 1 asc;
```

Comment: This is a situation where I only need the second last, I need the subquery (Select Count("Name")-1 FROM Rooms Where "Minimum">=7
and "Maximum"<=16) in order to obtain the actual number I need

Comment: So I all my subqueries and everything in there but I can't seem to get the syntax right